# Error 502 when calling a requests.get from an Azure Function App in Python

Tags: python, laravel, azure, message-queue, azure-function-app

I have this stack:

- A Laravel app hosted with Docker as a webapp on Azure;
- An external SOAP API;
- A Queue Trigger Azure Function App in Python.

The workflow is simple:

- Laravel dispatches a message to an Azure Storage Queue;
- The Queue Trigger starts and hits (with requests.get()) a Laravel endpoint (i.e. [host]/queue/queue-name), like this:

```
laravel_endpoint = os.environ['laravel_endpoint']
r = requests.get(laravel_endpoint)
```

- This route is connected to a controller that processes the queue, like this:

```
$queue = $request->route('queue', null);

if ($queue) {
    \Artisan::call('queue:work --queue='.$queue.' --stop-when-empty');
}
```

Logging the status code of the request (r.status_code), sometimes returns 502.

In that case, the code never reaches the controller, so the message is not processed.

We noticed this behaviour when the SOAP API returns a large amount of data.

There are no signs of this problem in the Apache logs, nor in the Laravel logs.

I've already tried raising the timeout and the memory for the Laravel queue, but, as said, when the endpoint returns a 502 error, the controller can't be reached.

Any ideas?

Comment: What about test it on local? Return 502 is useless, the key is to get the details error.

Comment: Everything works fine in local. Microsoft opened a ticket, let's see how it goes.